# CocoaPods having your pod to be a different project while you're developing it to avoid export/import cliff issues

Tags: import, localization, export, cocoapods, xliff

I am localizing my pod and it has dependencies. What's happening is when I try to export xliff file it contains all keys form related pods and also when I translated xliff and try to import this language I got many issues and conflicts.

So is it possible so my pod will be different project and localization will only touch my files?

Answer (score 0):

Just created empty project and dropped string files that should be localized... that all